# Windows 8 Access Denied when moving files

Tags: windows-8, permissions

I have a secondary drive that has been in multiple machines, both Windows 7 and Windows 8.  When trying to copy or move some of the files from this drive, I'm often presented with an "Access Is Denied" error.

I've adjusted ownership of the parent folders, and tried to set the permissions, but it seems that everything returns to where it was.

The machine is a Windows 8 machine.  Both user accounts configured on this machine are in the administrators group.

I have tried setting the permissions on folders in the security tab to FULL CONTROL; tried adjusting the ACLs as I understand them, etc.  I'm not seeing anything make a difference.

Where should I be looking?

Comment: Restrictions before Permissions...at some point there may still be restrictions overriding the set permissions

Comment: Ok, where would I look for that?

Comment: In Properties/Security/ klick Advanced Settings and go to the Ownership tab - try to take ownership. Might just be it.

Comment: I've already been there.  It hasn't changed anything.